# Android app compatibility with 2.2 and 4.0

Tags: android, compatibility

My App is coded with 2.2 "SdVersion 8" and when I run it in Ice Cream Sandwich I get the "Contex menu" down in botton right.

I want to take use of the new ICS interface. If I change the App to API-level 14 (Android 4.0) I get the new interface! (On 4.0 phone). BUT the App doesn't seem to start at all on phones with older Android-versions for example 2.2.

If I change minSdkVersion in the "API target 14" to 8 .. I get the old 2.2 interface on 4.0 devices.

So. Is it possible for an App to get the 2.2 interface on a 2.2 device, and 4.0 interface on a 4.0 device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to get the 4.0 interface on a 2.2 device without manually importing all of the resources you need from the Android source into your application and applying them correctly. The reason for this is all Android resources that are used to create the ICS theme are already on the phone. When you reference anything inside of the Android package you are actually referencing the Android version that is installed on a given device.

This is why for example when you open a dialog on an HTC device it looks different than it will on a Samsung device. Device manufactures usually customize some of these built in Android resources to give there device a special look than all other Androids.

So if you wanted to get the look of the ICS interface on all devices you could go into the android sdk you have downloaded and look in "pathToSDK/platforms/android-14/data/res". I would not suggest this as you might not get all of the required dependencies or you might have some conflicting styles that make it hard to see things. Also most users are comfortable with the theme they are used to seeing on their device and if there is an app that makes a major change to that it might take the user off guard.

Edit:

Sorry for my long winded answer as I think I misunderstood your question. You can get a 4.0 interface on a 4.0 and 2.2 interface on a 2.2 by setting the target sdk to 4.0 but leaving the min sdk on the lower setting. [This](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/optimizing-for-3.0.html#Optimizing) is a deprecated doc but will explain how to do what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the link! That did the trick... <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" 
              android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

Comment: Thanks for appending the real answer :) Themes work great with that settings, but since some control changed a lot over time, some extra work will be required to get similar behaviour on both platform versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can now also try the support library (appcompat v7 (library project), mediarouter v7 (library project), gridlayout v7 (library project), renderscript v8 (library jar), fragment backwards support v4 (library jar) v13 (library jar) ) from Google released with API Level 18. It can work all the way to 2.1 Eclair in some cases.

There is tutorials on how to import the library with Eclipse.

I have managed to do it with Netbeans Android plugin by adding it via the project properties in libraries section and then browse to the appcompat or other v7 project shown as android library project. The library jars are do